# How to clone an object (including its prototype) in ES2015

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, ecmascript-6

I'm cleaning up some old Backbone.js application, and rewriting most of it to ES2015.

I came across a place where we use Underscore.js to clone a model:

```
var modelCopy = _.clone(this.model);
```

Intuitively, I rewrote it to use `Object.assign`:

```
const modelCopy = Object.assign({}, this.model);
```

Turns out, `Object.assign` doesn't work quite like `_.clone` - it only gives me the properties and methods of the actual object - not its prototype.

I know Underscore is a dependency to Backbone no matter what, but I still wonder: how can I create an actual clone of an object with ES2015?

Comment: There is no built-in method if that's what you are asking. Use whatever you used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the prototype, you can use

```
const modelCopy = Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.model)), this.model)
```

Comment: ouch. ^^ I think I'll stick with the underscore method for pure readability reasons then :)